# Eliminate line numbers and filename from regex

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a regex that searches a file and returns matches.  It works fine, except it also gives me the filename and line number which I don't want.  I know I can eliminate that by using the Line property of the matches in general. But I am using the context param to get lines below the match and I can't seem to get it to work with that using the Context property or line property:

```
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex  -AllMatches  -context 0,7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex  -AllMatches  -Context 0,7 |
    Foreach {"> $($_.Line)";$_.Context.PostContext}
```

If you needed PreContext, use the `$_.Context.PreContext` property.

Comment: You could add `$_.Context.PreContext` anyway, because it won't show up when empty: `... | % { $_.Context.PreContext; $_.Line; $_.Context.PostContext }`